# How do nested templates get resolved in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, template-templates

I recently asked a question about determining whether an iterator points to a complex value at compile time and received an answer that works.

The question is here:
[How can I specialize an algorithm for iterators that point to complex values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59954327/how-can-i-specialize-an-algorithm-for-iterators-that-point-to-complex-values)

And the solution was a set of templates that determine whether one template is a specialization of another:

```
template <class T, template <class...> class Template>
struct is_specialization : std::false_type {};

template <template <class...> class Template, class... Args>
struct is_specialization<Template<Args...>, Template> : std::true_type {};
```

This does work, but I am really struggling to understand how this works. Particularly the nested `template` within a `template` is confusing to me. I'm also still fairly new to using variadic templates and it seems odd to have a variadic template with no type provided, for example: `<class...>` instead of something like this `<class... Args>`.

Can someone please break down this template and describe how it gets resolved?

Comment: please one question per quesiton. For the first see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I've read through the answers in that post and none of them seem to clearly describe how it works. They do show some use cases, but without knowing how it works none of the use cases really make sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to take in count that there are three types of template parameters:

1) types

2) non-types (or values)

3) template-templates

The first type is preceded by `typename` (or `class`)

```
template <typename T>
void foo (T const & t);
```

In the preceding example, `T` is a type and `t` (a classical function argument) is a value of type `T`.

The second type of template parameter are values and are preceded by the type of the value (or `auto`, starting from C++17, for a not specified type)

```
template <int I>
void bar ()
 { std::cout << I << std::endl; }
```

In the preceding example the `I` template parameter is a value of type `int`.

The third type is the most complex to explain.

Do you know (I suppose) that `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<double>` are different types, but they have in common `std::vector`, a template class.

A template-template parameter is a parameter that accept `std::vector`, the template class without arguments.

A template-template parameter is preceded by a `template` keyword, as in the following example

```
template <template <int> class C>
void baz ();
```

The template-template parameter `C` in the preceding example is class (or struct) that require a single `int` (value) template parameter.

So if you have a class

```
template <int I>
class getInt
 { };
```

you can pass `getInt`, as template parameter, to `baz()`

```
baz<getInt>();
```

Now you should be able to understand your code:

```
template <class T, template <class...> class Template>
struct is_specialization : std::false_type {};
```

the `is_specialization` struct is a template struct that receive, as template parameters, a type (`T`) and a template-template `Template` that accept classes/structs receiving a variadic number of type template parameters.

Now you have a specialization of `is_specialization`:

```
template <template <class...> class Template, class... Args>
struct is_specialization<Template<Args...>, Template> : std::true_type {};
```

This specialization is selected when the first template parameter (`Template<Args...>`) is a class based on the second (`Template`).

An example: if you instantiate

```
is_specialization<std::vector<int>, std::map>
```

the main version (that inherit from `std::false_type`) is selected because `std::vector<int>` isn't based on `std::map`.

But if you instantiate

```
is_specialization<std::vector<int>, std::vector>
```

the specialization (that inherit from `std::true_type`) is selected because `std::vector<int>` is based on `std::vector`.

Comment: I'm gonna need to read through this a few times and maybe take a few days and a few cups of coffee hahaha

Comment: @tjwrona1992 - yes, I suppose that you need to understand the concept of template-template parameter; not exactly trivial, IMHO.

Comment: I think I am somewhat beginning to grasp template-template parameters, but the fact that variadic templates are thrown into the mix is really making my head spin

Comment: @tjwrona1992 - take also in count that the rules to match the template parameters in template-template parameters and template parameters in matching arguments are complicated (and consider that I don't understand what I've just written) and have changed with C++17.

Comment: Does that mean that there may be a cleaner way to write this in C++17 and achieve the same result?

Comment: @tjwrona1992 - no, only that C++17 matches differently template-template parameters... but I see that I've great problems to say it in English; the best you can do is study this argument in a good book or in good articles.

Comment: Yes I'm thinking about picking up a copy of "C++ Templates: The Complete Guide" as recommended from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 0):

This is a answer based on what caused "click" in my head when it comes to this, I am sure max66 answer is much more useful if you can follow it. If like me even after reading about this you are still strugling here is my attempt to explain this.

**Do not read the first lines of  templates**

So this:

```
template <class T, template <class...> class Template>
struct is_specialization : std::false_type {};

template <template <class...> class Template, class... Args>
struct is_specialization<Template<Args...>, Template> : std::true_type {};
```

becomes this:

```
struct is_specialization : std::false_type {};

struct is_specialization<Template<Args...>, Template> : std::true_type {};
```

Now things are bit simpler. We have first general case, and second special case(that is prefered by compiler when he can match the arguments).
By match I do not mean anything fancy, almost literal text matching.

So for example if we do

```
is_specialization<std::vector<double>, std::set>
```

Now compiler will try to match special case.
You can imagine it literally replacing the `Template` with `std::vector` (if he is matching on the first argument first), and then fail since he now expects `Template` to mean `std::vector` and in the second argument it is `std::set`.
He also replaced `Args...` with `double` but that is not so important since that is not the cause of mismatch.

Similarly compiler could have first tried to match second argument and conclude that `Template` must be `std::set`, and then he fails since first argument is not `std::set<Args...>`.

I consider the first lines of templates much less important and easier to understand, but for completeness let's go over them.

```
template <class T, template <class...> class Template>
```

Just means that this is a template whose second arg is template template argument, this is needed so you can pass something like `std::set` as second argument(note that normally this will not work, you would need to pass `std::set` of some type, e.g. `std::set<float>`).

The ugliest part is the first line of second template:

```
template <template <class...> class Template, class... Args>
```

Here again if we remember what we do in specialization code makes sense.
We have template template argument `Template`, and `Args` are needed just because we want to use template template argument as normal template argument(as first arg(`Template<Args...>`)).

**tl;dr**

Ignore first lines of template, pattern match.

Disclaimer: Like I said this is just my way of explaining this code to myself, I know that standard people would cry reading phrases like "first line" or "pattern match".