# Concise way to specify I do not care about a template argument of my function argument?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

Consider following code:

```
int64_t signed_vector_size(const std::vector v){
    return (int64_t)v.size();
}
```

This does not work since std::vector is a template. But my function works for every T!

Easy fix is to just do

1)

```
template<typename T>
int64_t signed_vector_size(const std::vector<T>& v){
    return (int64_t)v.size();
}
```

or make the template implicit

2)

```
int64_t signed_vector_size(const auto& v){
    return (int64_t)v.size();
}
```

Or [concept based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51032862/700825), option 3.

```
template<class, template<class...> class>
inline constexpr bool is_specialization = false;
template<template<class...> class T, class... Args>
inline constexpr bool is_specialization<T<Args...>, T> = true;

template<class T>
concept Vec = is_specialization<T, std::vector>;

int64_t signed_vector_size(const Vec auto& v){
    return (int64_t)v.size();
}
```

I like the second solution, but it accepts any `v`, while I would like to limit it to the vector type only. Third is the best when just looking at the function, but specifying concepts is a relatively a lot of work.

Does C++20 syntax has any shorter way for me to specify that I want any `std::vector` as an argument or is the 1. solution the shortest we can do?

note: this is silly simplified example, *please* do not comment about how I am spending too much time to save typing 10 characters, or how I am sacrificing readability(that is my personal preference, I understand why some people like explicit template syntax).

Comment: Looks to me like you already have the minimal amount of code required to do this with your third example.

Comment: You could also change the first version to `template<typename... Ts> int64_t signed_vector_size(const std::vector<Ts...>& v)` to make it work in all cases

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but what's wrong with your #1 example?  That seems like it precisely and clearly specifies exactly what you mean.  #3 is a lot more complicated; now readers have to go look up what a `Vec` is and think about all of that template machinery.

Comment: #3 is also subtly different, as it allows anything that _inherits_ from `std::vector<T>` to work.

Comment: Solution 1 seems like the obvious choice to me

Answer (score 2):

Note that is **not** valid in standard C++20, but you can achieve exactly what you want with the following syntax that is supported by GCC as an extension.

```
std::vector<auto>
```

Which is shorthand for `std::vector<T>` where `T` is unconstrained.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6422d0284d299b85

Comment: Nice, I thought that it did not make it in C++20 since I only tried with clang... https://godbolt.org/z/nWxbEz

Comment: @NicolBolas That's why I deleted it. But apparently I can't re-delete it because it has been accepted.

Comment: I'm sorry, I voted to undelete the answer because it seemed ok. It's generally preferable to add a comment, or edit the answer indicating that you're deleting the answer because it's wrong.

Comment: I've rolled back, and added a disclaimer at the top. This way it's clearer to see the issue. Feel free to expand upon why the answer is wrong, and if the OP unaccepts, then go ahead and delete the answer.

Comment: unaccepted...  I would still leave the answer as we might get that in c++23

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl True. It also has value in that people who come across it will also learn that this syntax is not currently valid. I'll leave it up then.

Comment: I agree, the answer is useful. I also think it could be edited to simply state out that this is invalid C++20 that is supported by a GCC extension, and remove the bit about it being an incorrect answer originally.

Comment: I took the liberty of rewording your answer to skip the bit about you getting it wrong in the first revision. That's not really pertinent to the answer, and can always be looked up in the revision history if needed. Hope that's ok.

Answer (score 2):

A template is just a pattern for something. `vector` is the pattern; `vector<int, std::allocator<int>>` is a *type*. A function cannot take a pattern; it can only take a type. So a function has to provide an actual type.

So if you want a function which takes any instantiation of a template, then that function must itself be a template, and it must *itself* require everything that the template it takes as an argument requires. And this must be spelled out explicitly in the declaration of the function.

Even your `is_specialization` falls short, as it assumes that all template arguments are type arguments. It wouldn't work for `std::array`, since one of its arguments is a value, not a type.

C++ has no convenient mechanism to say what you're trying to say. You have to spell it out, or accept some less-than-ideal compromise.

Also, broadly speaking, it's probably not a good idea. If your function already must be a template, what would be the harm in taking any `sized_range`? Once you start expanding templates like this, you're going to find yourself less likely to be bound to specific types and more willing to accept any type that fulfills a particular concept.

That is, it's rare to have a function that is specific enough that it needs `vector`, but general enough that it doesn't have requirements on the `value_type` of that `vector` too.

Comment: In deleted(IDK why) answer Brian suggested std::vector<auto> https://godbolt.org/z/nWxbEz It works, but only gcc implemented it.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl I deleted it because I realized it wasn't actually valid C++20. I don't know why it got undeleted. I think you should unaccept it, so I can delete it again.

Answer (score 1):

How about this syntax?

```
int64_t signed_vector_size(const instance_of<std::vector> auto& v){
  return (int64_t)v.size();
}
```

Basically we want to be able to say "this argument should be an instance of some template".  So, say that?

```
template<template<class...>class Z, class T>
struct is_instance_of : std::false_type {};

template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
struct is_instance_of<Z, Z<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};

template<class T, template<class...>class Z>
concept instance_of = is_instance_of<Z, T>::value;

int64_t signed_vector_size(const instance_of<std::vector> auto& v){
  return (int64_t)v.size();
}
```

that should do it.  Note that I don't make a `Vec` alias; you can pass in partial arguments to a concept.  The type you are testing is **prepended**.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/8oYxh4).

Now, I'd actually say this is a bit of an anti-pattern.  I mean, that size?  Why shouldn't it work on non-vectors?  Like, `std::span`s or `std::deque`s.

Also, `instance_of` doesn't support `std::array`, as one of the arguments isn't a type.  There is no way to treat type, template and value arguments uniformly in C++ at this point.

For each pattern of type, template and value arguments you'd need a different concept.  Which is awkward.