# Why does std::visit in an unsatisfied concept cause a compile error in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, c++-concepts

This code:

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

struct any_callable {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T&&) {}
};

template<typename V>
concept is_variant = requires(V v) { std::visit(any_callable{}, v); };

int main() {
    constexpr bool wrapped = is_variant<std::string>;
}
```

does not compile under gcc 11. It gives a bunch of errors about `valueless_by_exception` and such. It does, however, compile under msvc ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xsc1fPazT)). Now as I understand concepts, in this instance, if it would usually fail to compile it will decay to false, otherwise to true. The behaviour of msvc would seem to support this.

So: Is this a bug in gcc, a non-standard feature of msvc, and/or is my code wrong?

Comment: Looks like not fully implemented - compiles in trunk (fails in clang 12, gcc 11) - https://godbolt.org/z/a1zsdoroW

Comment: using godbold conformance view: https://godbolt.org/z/GTqrW5Tor

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That this:

```cpp
template<typename V>
concept is_variant = requires(V v) { std::visit(any_callable{}, v); };
```

works at all is a very recent change, a result of [P2162](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2162r2.html). In order for this check to work, you need `std::visit` to be what's usually referred to as "SFINAE-friendly". That is: it must somehow be constrained on "variant-ness" such that if `V` is a variant, it works, and if `V` is not a variant, then `visit` is removed from the overload set such that this call is an invalid expression (so that the `concept` can be rejected).

However, prior to P2162, there were no *Constraints* on `std::visit`. It was not SFINAE-friendly: the call would either work or be ill-formed. It was this paper that *added* the constraint that the types that you're passing into it are variants (or inherit from one). That's why you're seeing the error you're seeing: the call to `visit` was failing, but not in a way that was friendly to the `concept` check.

Post-P2162 (which, as the paper points out, MSVC already implemented, but libstdc++ did not), your check will be valid.

But we can do this easier in C++20 without having to go into the variant machinery - by checking the variant-ness directly in the same way that the paper does it:

```cpp
template<typename V>
concept is_variant = requires(V v) {
    []<typename... Ts>(std::variant<Ts...> const&){}(v);
};
```

That lambda is invocable with `v` if either `v` is a `variant` or it inherits from one. Otherwise, it's ill-formed. This is more straight-forward than going through `visit`.

Comment: As SFINAE based dispatching is hopefully consigned to the dustbin of "old hacks" (ok not quite) and is less important, maybe we should call it something else.  Early and Late failure?

Comment: This concept seems to be an [elegant boilerplate](https://godbolt.org/z/M1vKMznvM) that can detect "whether it is std::xxx" in C++20.

Comment: @康桓瑋 There's no reason to use `declval` (you almost never need that thing with concepts) - the way I did it is more straightforward.

Comment: Barry this is a style thing, but I like Casey way of checking, is there a reason you prefer lambda(except handling inheritance )? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51032862/700825

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl The trait's better long-term, since you probably need to do this multiple times.